# What does 亲你一口 mean?

Tags: word-choice, word

I thought 亲你一口 means “kiss you” but usually, I think verbs take 一下 to add the meaning of “a bit”.

So why is it 亲你一口, not 亲你一下, and what does it differ from just say 亲你? Or is the relationship between 亲你 and 亲你一口 the same as between 看你 and 看你一下?

Comment: 看手？ 亲你一口 can be compared to 看你一眼，body parts are used as verb measure words

Comment: see e.g. https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%87%8F%E8%AF%8D 动量词 e.g. 他踢了我一脚。我打了他一巴掌。老师瞪了我一眼 has been discussed at this site before (in fact in response to same OP, still trying to find this previous Q&A)

Comment: previous Q&A where comments touch on present topic has been found, see comments of
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/27107/what-does-%e4%b8%80%e7%95%aa-mean-in-%e4%b8%8e5%e5%b9%b4%e5%89%8d%e7%9b%b8%e6%af%94%e7%bf%bb%e4%ba%86%e4%b8%80%e7%95%aa/27114#27114

Comment: Maybe you could translate like this: 亲你 kiss you, 亲你一口 give you a kiss; 看你 look at you, 看你一眼 give you a glimpse.

Comment: using 亲 as a verb classifier and  write 亲你一亲 is the more common practice,  along with 亲你一下; 亲你一口 just doesn't sound native

Comment: 口 as verb CL: bkrs: for oral activities:bite,sting,gulp,sip,drag (inhaling),puff,咬[他]一口,吸一口烟

Comment: 口 as a  classifier is similar to 'a bite of' or 'a mouthful of' in English. It is not appropriate for 'kiss'

Comment: exactly, 2nd last comment was intended to confirm that verbal CL 口 is used for other oral activities, however also see iciba: 
宁可让贤明的人打一耳光,也不愿傻瓜来亲一口.
Better a slap from the wise than a kiss from a fool.
中国第十届国际影展入选作品名单 ... 黄蕙英 Huang Huiying 亲一口 Let me kiss you 李旻 Li Min.

Comment: @TangHo, Why do you think "亲你一口 just doesn't sound native"? In fact, it does.

Comment: @xbh Yes but then what is the difference between 亲你一口 and 亲你一下? Or 看你一眼 and 看你一下?

Comment: @Blaszard Basically interchangable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

亲你一口 and 亲你一下 mean the same, *kiss one time*. 口 and 下 are both valid measure words for 亲. So, 亲一口 == 亲一下.

You should note that 一下 doesn't **ALWAYS** mean '*a bit*'. It can mean '*one time*'. For example, 打三下（hit three times）， 亲两下(kiss two times).

Comment: Thanks so how can I use them apart between 亲你一口 and 亲你一下?

Comment: @Blaszard you can replace one with the other.